# How to use nested class in C++?

Tags: c++, nested-class

I'm implementing a Timer such that the time spent on different kinds of events are categorized and listed. The class declaration goes something as follows:

```
#include "timer_event.h"
#include <boost/timer.hpp>
#include <vector>

class Timer {
 private:
  class TimedEvent;
 public:
  static TimedEvent* Time(TimerEvent e);
 protected:
 private:
  class TimedEvent {
       public:
    TimedEvent(double seconds, TimerEvent event);
    ~TimedEvent();
   protected:
   private:
    TimerEvent event_;
    double seconds_;
  };
  static boost::timer watch_;
};
```

Then, in the source file, I'm planning to implement the "Time" function as something like:

```
TimedEvent* Time(TimerEvent e) {
  TimedEvent* ret = new TimedEvent(watch_.elapsed(),e);
  return ret;
}
```

However, the compiler's error message is:

```
../utils/timer.cc:24:1: error: ‘TimedEvent’ does not name a type
```

Could anyone try to help?

---

--Revised:

I've modified the Time function so that it now looks like:

```
Timer::TimedEvent* Timer::Time(TimerEvent e) {
  TimedEvent* ret = new TimedEvent(watch_.elapsed(),e);
  return ret;
}
```

However, since "Time" is declared as a static function in the class declaration. We need to declare the static objects in the cpp file since I'm getting this in the linker's error message:

```
timer.cc:(.text+0x76): undefined reference to `Timer::TimedEvent::TimedEvent(double, TimerEvent)'
```

What kind of static object should I declare in the source file then?

Comment: Remove all elements from your testcase that don't relate to the question/problem, please.

Comment: Did you really have to make `TimerEvent` and `TimedEvent` have such similar names?

Comment: @AusCBloke: Actually TimerEvent is just an enumeration of events that I'm trying to keeping track of the execution time...cannot think of a better name that fits...I do agree that TimerEvent and TimedEvent are too similar...

Comment: @derekhh oh ok. I just know that if it was me, I'd probably be making plenty of typos and doing my head in over the two, especially since the D and R keys are so close too. ;)

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Just revised the post for a more detailed problem...

Comment: @derekhh: You appear to have added an entirely new question. And I don't think `static` has anything to do with it; why do you think that the `static` is pertinent?

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: I see...seems even if I do not use the static modifier to "Time", the same problem still occurs...

Comment: @derekhh: Well, you didn't define `Timer::TimedEvent`'s constructor. Fairly self-explanatory!

Comment: @TomalakGeret'kal: Got it...I really should have at least read the codes again before I made the post...Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a compiler error, not a linker error.

Presumably your `Time` was supposed to look like this:

```
TimedEvent* Timer::Time(TimerEvent e) {
   TimedEvent* ret = new TimedEvent(watch_.elapsed(),e);
   return ret;
}
```

I really dislike how everything starts with "Time", by the way!

Now, inside the function you can probably use `TimedEvent` as it is. But the return type isn't inside the function: you'll have to qualify the type as `Timer::TimedEvent` for that:

```
Timer::TimedEvent* Timer::Time(TimerEvent e) {
   TimedEvent* ret = new TimedEvent(watch_.elapsed(),e);
   return ret;
}
```

In addition, you need to define `Timer::TimedEvent`'s constructor somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

In the source file, you should implement `Time` as:

```
Timer::TimedEvent Timer::Time( TimerEvent e ) { ... }
```

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal: It looks `TimerEvent` and `TimedEvent` are different types, `TimerEvent` having its own header, but I'm not really sure about that... Even if the argument were `TimedEvent`, I believe once in the parameter list the compiler would already know that the scope of the function is `Timer`.

Comment: Well spotted. What a horrid naming scheme!